# how to filter an numpy.ndarray by a spevific number?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filter

```
roi_pixel_img = crop_img[indices_list]
print (roi_pixel_img)
```

[image]

when i add (I use only to use the entire array (meaning only a part):

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
```

th output is:

[image]

the whole part happens in a while loop because I'm extracting pixels in this section, which is irrelevant to the question.

My goal is not to include the lines with [0 255 255] in this array, how can I do that?

the type of roi_pixel_img is numpy.ndarray.

is it even possible to answer this question without an example code for you ?

Comment: What is your array's shape? (`roi_pixel_img.shape`)

Comment: its variable, for example (6730, 3). i mean the only variable part that is the first, fixed is 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating an indexing array:

```
r = (roi_pixel_img == [0,255,255]).all(axis = -1)

roi_pixel_img[~r]
```

The `roi_pixel_img == [0,255,255]` statement will result in an array with the same shape as `roi_pixel_img` (say `(N, 3)`) and will compare element-wise, eg `[0,255,0]` will result in `[True, True, False]`. Using `.all(axis = -1)` Will reduce along the last axis (in this case `axis = 1` would produce the same result) and will result in `True` if all the element match. So `r` will have shape `(N, )`.

Using `~r` to index will exclude the matching pixels and due to the shape will be broadcast appropriately by `numpy`.

Comment: works! could you explain why do you use .all on axis ?